# Cast Date in SQL CriteriaBuilder API

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to filter out rows on basis of date string passed from frontend.

I am passing following from front end :

```
let data = {
     createddate1: '2019-03-14'
    };
```

The column is of type `datetime` in sql server table and have following entries :

```
id,createddate
1,2019-03-14 11:20:00.000
2,2019-03-14 11:22:00.000
3,2019-03-14 11:25:00.000
4,2019-03-14 11:27:00.000
```

I am trying to implement following query

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ABC] where cast( CREATEDDATE as date) = '2019-03-14';
```

in following manner :

```
    public static Specification<ABCDetails> getABCList(
                String createddate1){
    return (root, query, cb) ->{
    ParameterExpression<Date> param = cb.parameter(Date.class, createddate1);
    cb.equal(root.<Date>get("createddate"), param));
    };
    }
```

The Entity class is as follows :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="ABC")
public class ABCDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "CREATEDDATE")
    private Date createddate;
}
```

I am getting exception as

```
 Error message: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
expecting IDENT, found '2019' near line 1, column 144 [select generatedAlias0 
from com.ow.domain.ABCDetails as generatedAlias0
where generatedAlias0.createddate=:2019-03-14]; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found 
'2019' near line 1, column 144 [select generatedAlias0 from 
com.ow.domain.ABCDetails as generatedAlias0 where
 generatedAlias0.createddate=:2019-03-14]
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Could u try this ?? 
`cq.equal(cb.substring(root.get("createddate"),1,7),'2019-03-14');`

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Comment: `root.get("createddate").as(String.class)`. Replace with this.

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 it is giving empty string,can you give me direction in converting below sql in criteria builder. ```SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ABC] where convert(VARCHAR(10),CREATEDDATE,102) = '2019.03.14';```

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 as per my understanding, i have created below for it ```cb.equal(cb.function("CONVERT", String.class, root.get("createddate"), cb.literal(102)), cb.literal(createddate))```

Comment: while casting it is giving empty string? Can you post the query it generated..?

Comment: Finally it works.. ??

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 yes but date format is changed.what small thing can be missing here. It is accepting ```Mar 14 2019``` but not ```2019-03-14```

Comment: Because for the substring function you need to use string data-type that is the reason we changing it to string.

Comment: How can we make it work with ```2019-03-14``` as this is most common accepted format?

Comment: while fetching from DB what is the date format do u get.. ?

Comment: Be aware that casting the "column" value might affect performance heavily. It's better to cast/convert the parameter to the right type, e.g.: SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ABC] where CREATEDDATE = cast( '2019-03-14' as date);